# MinionPro package works fine included in a document, throws dozens of errors when required by a class file

Tags: packages, document-classes, documentclass-writing, minionpro

I have the following M(N)WE—minimum (not) working example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{class.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{class}[20/07/14 A class]

    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[minionint,lf,mathtabular,loosequotes,swash,opticals,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
    \LoadClass{exam}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{class}
% \usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

With a working install of Minion Pro, using the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) tool, the above code does **not** compile, throwing around 80 errors. A complete log from the VS Code LaTeX Workshop tool is [here](https://pastebin.com/4JJ76WBu).

On the other hand, uncommenting the line `\usepackage{MinionPro}`, and commenting out the `\RequirePackage[...]{MinionPro}` line **works**, and the document is now properly typeset in Minion Pro.

What may I do to fix this? I am authoring a class that makes heavy use of Minion Pro, and I would really like to get this working.

---

I am using MiKTeX, Windows 10, and VS Code with the LaTeX Workshop tool running Latexmk as the build tool.

Comment: This isn't a fair comparison. What happens if you don't include any extra options in your RequirePackage, to match the usepackage? If that works fine, you could add the options back in and figure out which one(s) are problematic

Comment: Well read the errors: the first complains that \normalsize doesn't exist. Load the font package  after loading the exam class.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Fox and @Ulrike Fischer.

Getting rid of the additional options didn't make the file compile, but it *did* narrow down the issue to the `\normalsize` error, which was then fixed by swapping the load order. Would you care to type out a response, so I may mark it as an answer?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error in your log reads like this:

```
....\MinionPro-FontDef.sty:44: 
LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.
 
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                 
l.44   \normalsize
                  \@nil
```

Which gives you a good clue what it is wrong: You didn't loaded a class yet and some commands are missing that the font package expects.

Load the font package after the `\LoadClass{exam}`.